# How can i return unique values horizontally based off another list on Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, unique, horizontallist

I have table that looks like this from A1-B10

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | ID | Animal |
| *2* | TEST1 | Zebra |
| *3* | TEST2 | Zebra |
| *4* | TEST4 | Zebra |
| *5* | TEST1 | Giraffe |
| *6* | TEST2 | Giraffe |
| *7* | TEST4 | Monkey |
| *8* | TEST5 | Monkey |
| *9* | TEST5 | Cat |
| *10* | TEST1 | Cat |

Currently i look down the B1-B10 list and copy and paste to column C,D,E...etc

So a formula should be able to look for all the Animals associated with Tests and populate all results horizontally.

| ID | Animal | Animal | Animal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | Zebra | Giraffe | Cat |
| TEST2 | Zebra | Giraffe |  |
| TEST3 |  |  |  |
| TEST4 | Zebra | Monkey |  |
| TEST5 | Monkey | Cat |  |

Answer (score 3):

### Return Matches in Columns

In `D2` (also return unique values; none can be missing):

```
=LET(Data,A2:B10,uCol,1,vCol,2,
    ud,INDEX(Data,,uCol),vd,INDEX(Data,,vCol),
    u,SORT(UNIQUE(ud)),
    v,IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",u,LAMBDA(rr,r,
        VSTACK(rr,TOROW(FILTER(vd,ud=r))))),1),""),
HSTACK(u,v))
```

[image]

In `J2` (`I2:I6` already contains the unique values; some may be missing):

```
=LET(Data,A2:B10,uCol,1,vCol,2,lData,I2:I6,
    ud,INDEX(Data,,uCol),vd,INDEX(Data,,vCol),
IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",lData,LAMBDA(rr,r,
    VSTACK(rr,TOROW(FILTER(vd,ud=r,""))))),1),""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one single dynamic array formula to spill, here are two alternatives, also you can use `Power Query` to perform this task.

---

**Using Formulas**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B$10,$D2=$A$2:$A$10,""))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down, while the formulas are one single dynamic array formulas which spills.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(
a,A2:A10,
b,B2:B10,
ua,UNIQUE(a),
HSTACK(VSTACK(A1,ua),IFERROR(REDUCE(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(B1&"|",3),"|",,1),ua,LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,TOROW(FILTER(b,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(a,y)),""))))),"")))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(array,A2:A10,
Col,COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10),
VSTACK(HSTACK($A$1,TEXTSPLIT(REPT($B$1&"|",SEQUENCE(,MAX(Col))),"|",,1)),
IFERROR(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A10,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(array),MAX(Col),
LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FILTER(B2:B10,array=INDEX(array,r)),c))))),"")))
```

---

Or, **Using Power Query**

[image]

---

To perform the above task using `Power Query` follow the steps:

• First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

• Next, open a blank query from `Data` Tab --> `Get & Transform Data` --> `Get Data` --> `From Other Sources` --> `Blank Query`

---

• The above lets the `Power Query` window opens, now from `Home` Tab --> `Advanced Editor` --> And paste the following by removing whatever you see, and press `Done`

```
M-Code:
```

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"All", each _, type table [ID=text, Animal=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"ID", "Animal", "Index"}, {"ID", "Animal", "Index"}),
    #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {{"Index", each "Animal " & Text.From(_, "en-US"), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Prefix", List.Distinct(#"Added Prefix"[Index]), "Index", "Animal")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

• Lastly, to import it back to `Excel` --> Click on `Close & Load` or `Close & Load To` --> The first one which clicked shall create a new sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula in `F2` to return all animals of TEST!

```
=TOROW(FILTER(B2:B10,A2:A10=E2,""))
```

[image]